# What is the evidence to repudiate this version of the "stab in the back" myth?

Tags: nazi-germany, germany, world-war-one, antisemitism

The [Stab in the Back Myth](http://www.dailystormer.com/the-german-revolution-of-1918-and-the-stab-in-the-back-myth/)

Among claims that need context and checking:

> The Jewish Lord Rothschild used his connections with American Jewry to get America into the war. This was, of course, very easy for the Jews there, who were in control of the media and were serving in senior government functions. In return, the British Foreign Secretary Lord Balfour wrote a declaration, promising the Jews their own Zionist state in Palestine.

While there is no evidences of this beyond the delaration's existence, context is removed.

> The Marxist Jews in Germany organized strikes and revolutions. Hitler expands on this in his book. These Jews were trying to stir division between the Bavarians and the Prussians, between the common man and the aristocracy, etc. Also they did their best to agitate the soldiers against their government.

Most sources point out that the revolutions were having no effect on the war.

What historical evidence refutes these claims?

Comment: The first thing you should do is read a reputable history book. It will tell you that the German generals, not civilian leaders, demanded an armistice, because they were losing in the battlefield.

Comment: A reasonable person who reads these two sentences, even if s/he does not know much about history, immediately sees that this is anti-semitic propaganda.

Comment: What is it that you want to know? Can you focus the question?  Questions where the title clearly indicates what you want to know tend to get answers.

Comment: If you really don't know much about history, just stop reading this sort of articles and debunking them. Learn from some reliable sources.

Comment: Your country being in a civil war run by Rosa Luxembourg and her fellow judeo-Bolsheviks has no effect on world war I? What?

Comment: The article you cited is from a site which is known to be hub of Modern Nazi sympathizers. They thrive on such drivel and falsehoods. As suggested before, instead of giving too much thought to the outright lies & fairytales of racist imbeciles, read history books, they will do you  much good

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stab-in-the-back_myth may be helpful, doesnt debunk it though.

Comment: The myth is several claims: 1) Germany could have won 2) if not for these revolts 3) that where mostly instigatetd by communists (and Jews) 4) revolting for bread and against war and monarchy is somehow bad. The last one is a political discussion, 1-3 are about historical facts. You can get better answers by focussing on the facts ("good questions have answers") and showing us your research (so our answers are not redundant).

Comment: I'm surprised at how much criticism this question is getting.

Comment: Also,Lord Rothschild was British, so why wouldn't he attempt to aid Britain by helping being America in?

Answer (score 12):

I think this article is a very sinister form of hatred propaganda. It is sinister because it makes a statement which is virtually impossible to debunk. Consider the fact that there are many million Jews around the world. Among these you will find some that are communists, other that are capitalists, and so on. That is no different from other ethnic groups. This doesn't mean that the Jews are conspiring only because there are Jewish revolutionaries in Russia. So, you can't debunk the article, but you can read it for what it is, hate propaganda.

Comment: That whole website is based on hatred and idiocy.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with the "causes" of events there are no facts. You are in the world of interpretation and opinion.

Characterizing the American entry into the war as the sole product of a Rothschild PR campaign is as ridiculous as it is unprovable.

Your statement that the revolutions were having no effect on the war seems incorrect to me. To which "sources" are you referring? One of the main pressures on the Germans to agree to the armistice was that people were rioting in the streets and it was getting worse. There were mutinies occurring left and right on both sides. If you think this does not have an effect on the calculations of military leaders, you are mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

The stab in the back idea held by Hitler, retorts to the signing of the Versailles treaty. If you listen to Benjamin Freedmon who was at Versailles, he states that 129 dignitaries from the German side were Jewish and the signatories on the actual treaty were of German-Jewish descent. Hitler vowed that his work was to destroy the treaty of Versailles in its entirety hence the Jewish stab in the back; Rightly or wrongly!

Comment: Any references to back the statements in your answer?

Comment: I cannot find any record of "Benjamin Freedmon" - I can find references to "Benjamin Freedman" on several websites that seem more interested in persuasion that scholarship.  For these reasons, I'm less than confident in this answer.

Comment: "129" is an extravagantly specific number, with no linked reference.

Answer (score -1):

"The stab in the back" hypothesis came from General Ludendorff not Hitler...and was directed at the German people not any particular ethnic group per se.

Hitler turned it into "the Jews" most likely out of political convenience. Not only were many Jews at the Vanguard of Marxist/Leninism thus literally invading Poland in 1920 but also there were Jews who were fanatical Nazi's since they lost so much property when the Communists took over in Russia.

In short the Jews were very vulnerable going into the "existential struggle in the East" and made a very simple political foil...for all of Europe actually...as they were consistently on the worst side of both sides in World War 2.

Stalin and Russia had no problem liquidating the Jews prior to the outbreak of open hostilities with Nazi Germany...but observing these same Jews now at the Vanguard of a Nazi Invasion of Mother Russia (Google SS Mayor of Moscow) the Russians were to give no quarter to the Jew once the war went bad for the Nazi's. Denmark defended the crafty conniver....but that was it. Even the USA became disgusted with their incessant demands for a "Jewish State" ... and gave them just that as clearly 9 million dead was just a "downpayment." Leaving that ugly History aside however "the stab in the back" had more to do with the failure of the German people to trust in their "Fatherland" hence the cataclysms that befell Germany following the Armistice of 1918.

Needless to say no one made this argument about the Germans circa 1933-1945...